# PHP set a variables from $_GET['var']

Tags: php

Is it possible to set a variables value from a `$_GET['var']` doing somthing like this:

```
if( $foo = isset($_GET['foo']) ) // Or something close to this. 
I.e if $_GET['foo'] is set assign it's value then and there
```

instead of this like I currently do

```
if( isset($_GET['foo']) )
$foo = $_GET['foo'];
```

This is ok when it's just one or two, but like me when you have 10+ $_GET's it gets ugly.

Comment: I see this asked now and then. Apparently, nobody thinks of writing custom functions to solve repetitive code tasks ;-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - the odds are he hasn't thought of using functions *at all*.

Answer (score 1):

user ternary operator

```
 $foo = isset($_GET['foo']) ? $_GET['foo'] : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

try

> ```
> $foo = !empty($_GET['foo']) ? $_GET['foo'] : null;
> ```

Comment: @Suresh Kamrushi is aheading me

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You can do it in shorthand with a ternary statement, but that's not a great deal less clunky.

The best you can do might be to write a function like the following:

```
function extractFromGet(array $keys) {
    $ret = []; // empty array

    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $ret[$key] = isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : null;
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

You can then call it as follows:

```
list ($name, $email, $telephone, $address) = extractFromGet(
    ['name', 'email', 'telephone', 'address']
);
```